# Multi-Criteria Multi-Salesman Time-Dependant Routing Problem

Tags: path-finding

So I'm looking for potential solutions to a complex pathing/route-finding problem.

Say I have a number of required appointments. These appointments happen generally on a weekly cycle, but can diverge from this (IE two weekly). Each appointment has a certain amount of time that must be spent there.

Each of these appointments has a number of criteria attached that must be upheld:

1. Time dependence - Appointments must be set either between a range of times, or at a particular, critical time
2. Skills dependence - Certain appointments can only be attended by certain staff members (IE qualification requirements)
3. Preferences - It is preferred as an example that appointments are attended to by those with more previous appointments with the same client - these are not "hard" limitations and can by bypassed if needed

Given the above problems I'm looking to develop a solution that minimises the travel cost between the appointments (IE Multi-Salesman) whilst ensuring the above criteria are met on a daily basis.

My initial reaction was to break this down into different problems. The first being the Time the appointments are happening, and the second being the route-finding between those appointments. Given the complex nature of the requirements I worry that this will end up with certain appointments being unreachable (IE the only staff member who can complete the call is too far away).

Are there any existing algorithms / solutions that can deal with complex route-planning of this nature?

Answer (score 0):

This could be approached from a [constraint programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming) angle

> In computer science, constraint programming is a programming paradigm
>   wherein relations between variables are stated in the form of
>   constraints. Constraints differ from the common primitives of
>   imperative programming languages in that they do not specify a step or
>   sequence of steps to execute, but rather the properties of a solution
>   to be found.

There are many libraries for different languages available (listed in that wikipedia article)

What you describe is a  [Constraint satisfaction problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem)